# Extract amount + prefix / suffix for monetary value in python

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract these from a text:

1. the amount + prefix / suffix of the currency format
2. any other numeric value

The currency format can be represented in various combination and for different currencies, i.e. usd, usd$, us$, eur, etc. Example below shows only for USD currency.

**Example:**

```
text = 'usd$4540.34, some text, usd $1234.34, $123.98, $234, $ 123, USD$1621.09, usd109, 123usd, 8888, some other text, foo, bar'
```

So far I have this code:

```
re.sub(r"[^(\w{1,})?\$?\d.*\.?\d*$]|[^0-9$+.,\s']", '', text, flags=re.I).strip(',')
```

But it is returning this **result**:

```
'$4540.34,,$1234.34,$123.98,$234,$123,$1621.09,109,123,8888'
```

Based on the example above, the regex should return this **expected output**:

```
usd$4540.34, usd $1234.34, $123.98, $234, $ 123, USD$1621.09, usd109, 123usd, 8888
```

Appreciate if anyone could help me on this. Thanks!

Comment: hi @Mandy8055, yup it did. managed to tweak the regex to include 8888 too. thanks for the help!

Comment: yup that will be good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below regex for your purpose:

```
^(?:(?:[a-z]{0,} ?\$? *)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$|^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]{1,})$
```

**Explanation of the above Regex:**

> **`^, $`** - Represents start and end of the String respectively.
>
> **`?:`** - Represents non-capturing group
>
> **`(?:[a-z]* ?\$? *)`** - Represents the cases which contains **$ and usd**(according to your example) in the beginning. It can contain zero or more white-spaces in between them or before the starting of numerical value.**You need to edit the regex here also in order to add other currency symbols like ₹, €, etc.**
>
> **`\d+`** - Matches a digit 1 or more times.
>
> **`(?:\.\d+)?`** - A non-capturing group matching the decimal part 0 or 1 time.
>
> **|** - Represents alternation
>
> **`(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]{1,})`** - A non-capturing group which is used for matching the case where the currency follows the digits.(**123usd** as in your case).

You can find the demo of the above regex [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/AYy85M/6)

**Implementation in python:**

```
import re
regex =  r"^(?:(?:[a-z]{0,} ?\$? *)\d+(?:\.\d+)?)$|^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]{1,})$"
text = 'usd$4540.34, some text, usd $1234.34, $123.98, $234.32.2, $ 123, USD$1621.09, usd109, 123usd, 8888, some other text, foo, bar, 998.90'
text = text.replace(', ', '\n')
print(re.findall(regex, text, flags=re.I | re.M))
```

You can find the sample run [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/HkPErFGoI) You can although manipulate the code according to your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

This gives directly as list :

```
pattern = r'((?:[a-z]+ ?)?(?:[$] *)?\d+(?:\.\d+)?[a-z]*)'
text = 'usd$4540.34, some text, usd $1234.34, $123.98, $234, $ 123, USD$1621.09, usd109, 123usd, 8888, some other text, foo, bar'
re.findall(pattern, text, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: Hi @Philippe. Your regex may accept some unfavorable strings too. Please see [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/U57JxP/1). I will recommend that you use the word boundaries or multiline flag along with start and end delimiter to make your regex more efficient and specific.